# Python "invalid index to scalar variable" using RandomForestClassifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I got an error "invalid index to scalar variable" in this line:

> predicted = [[index, x[1]] for index, x in enumerate(rf.predict(test), start = 1)]

I know, there was solution for similar problem, but I should output solution in my code with two columns, where first is index, second - prediction. So, I used **enumerate** method for counting index from 1 to n, and I have no idea how to fix my error, couse I'm new with Python and things like list comphrehations. Thanks for any help.

```
def main():    
    dataset = genfromtxt(open('train.csv', 'r'), delimiter = ',', dtype = 'int64')[1:]
    target = [x[0] for x in dataset]
    train = [x[1:] for x in dataset]
    test = genfromtxt(open('test.csv', 'r'), delimiter = ',', dtype = 'int64')[1:]
    rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 1000, n_jobs = CPU)
    rf.fit(train, target)

    predicted = [[index, x[1]] for index, x in enumerate(rf.predict(test), start = 1)]
    savetxt('submission_randomf2.csv', predicted, delimiter=',', fmt='%d,%f', header='ImageId,Label', comments = '')    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: What does `rf.predict(test)` return? Presumably at least one of the items returned is a scalar, so trying to index it as `x[1]` fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here `rf.predict(test)` is a 1D array as the output dimension is one (see [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html)).

Try the following:

```
predicted = [[index, x] for index, x in enumerate(rf.predict(test), start = 1)]
```